# Arrange UIView subviews in relation to outside UIViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

How do I arrange (in terms of depth) a view's subview to be in front of another view?

The hierarchy looks like this:

```
A--
   -C
   -D
B--
   -E
   -F
```

(A and B are views with C & D, and E & F, as subviews, respectively.)

B is layered above A, so every subview in B (E and F) is above every subview in A (C and D). How can I make C display above everything in B, but have the rest remain as it should be?

In other words, how can I make the order of displayed views (the first in the list is the topmost, with the next one drawn *behind* it):

```
C
B
E & F (same level)
A
D
```

Thanks,
Arseniy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it the way you describe it. Either view A or B is frontmost, if you want to show view C in front of view B, but want to keep A and D behind it, you need to take C out of view A and show it at the same level as A & B.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be the case. Taking C out of view A is the only way to do it, and that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using UIView methods to move/relocate views?

```
insertSubview:aboveSubview:
insertSubview:atIndex:
insertSubview:belowSubview:
addSubViews:
bringSubviewToFront:
removeFromSuperview:
```

Comment: Those only work in relation to the view of which it is a subview. Those don't alter the order of views in relation to other unrelated superviews.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want C to display above everything in B, make it a subview of B.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make C a parent view of both A and B. This should do what you want.

```
C
  -B
    -E
    -F
  -A
    -D
```

Use the functions in [Managing the view hierarchy](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW46) to rearrange your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Is A and B UIViewControllers? And C,D,E,F UIViews added to these controllers? You're not being very clear.

If they are all subViews of a UIViewController then see my earlier post.